# IOS: drag uiimageview only in one direction

Tags: ios, xcode, drag

I want to drag an uiimageview only in horizontal from a point1 to a point2; how can I do it?

Comment: I know well UIDragRecognizer , but I don't have idea for control the drag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use somting like this:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
      touchStart = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:/*your main view*/];
        point1 = CGPointMake(140, 140);
        oldrect = imgview.rect;

}

    - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
      CGPoint point = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:/*your main view*/];
      imgview.center = CGPointMake(imgview.center.x + point.x - touchStart.x, imgview.center.y);
    }

    -(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        CGPoint point = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:/*your main view*/];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25
                         animations:^{

    if (((point1.x -15) > point.x) && ((point1.x + 15 ) < point.x) {
            Imgview.rect = CGRectMake(point.x, point.x, imgview.frame.size.width,imgview.frame.size.height);
        }
    else {Imgview.rect = oldrect;}
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){ }];}  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, check your imageView x position and your touch x position

float lastX = myimageview.center.x;

if the touch point x is bigger than lastX (or smaller, depends on the direction you want) 
{
 // Do the move
} else {
 // Do nothing
}

Your code should look something like that :

```
- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
    // Move relative to the original touch point
    CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    float lastX = myimageview.center.x;
    if (pt.x > lastX){
       // move myimageview.x to pt.x
    }
}
```